# build fails on Xcode due the one signal library

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I have been trying this for few days now but still I had no luck building it successfully.

The error I get is:**'React/RCTAnimationType.h' file not found**

I have already added into **header search path** this $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/ios and made it recursive.

Do I need to run pod install or anything like that? If anyone would help me on this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you try using `react-native link react-native-onesignal` in terminal in the project dir ?

Comment: yes I have tried that, no luck!

Comment: Looks like your issue is solved here: https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/306